# In WaitForSingleObject, is timeout=INFINITE the same as timeout=-1?

Tags: waitforsingleobject

I'm working with some Visual Basic for Applications (VB 6.3) code written by someone else, and they've written:

```
WaitForSingleObject SEI.hProcess, -1
```

The process this appears in is supposed to return some data in a text box; sometimes it fails to return anything, and I think it's because of this, possibly because it's its timing out. Is that code the same as:

```
WaitForSingleObject SEI.hProcess, INFINITE
```

???

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9):

The timeout for [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is actually a `DWORD`, which is an *unsigned* 32 bit integer.  `INFINITE` is defined as `0xFFFFFFFF`, but -1 mapped into an unsigned type wraps and becomes this value in most integer representations.

> Is that code the same as:

Effectively, yes.

Comment: -1 would be mapped to 0xFFFFFFFF even if the integer representation was something weird, since that conversion is not specified to be a reinterpretation of the bitpattern but taking the value modulo 2^N where N is the number of bits (see [conv.integral] ). For two's complement integers that's the same thing as reinterpreting the bitpattern, but otherwise the result has to be the same even if that costs a more-involved conversion.

Answer (score 0):

So basically your question translates to whether `WaitForSingleObject SEI.hProcess, -1` and `WaitForSingleObject SEI.hProcess, INFINITE` are same or not?

As Reed's answer says, yes, they are same and so is `WaitForSingleObject SEI.hProcess, -3999`. Basically any negative number will wrap around and become the maximum unsigned int available which is coincidentally the value of `INFINITE`.

Now, does it mean you should use either of these. NO. You should always use the documented version otherwise C++ is very famous to have undefined behaviour for undocumented features.